# vue-select is showing ID instead of option value

Tags: vue.js

I am using this https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#caveats-with-reduce library for my application dropdown option.

```
<v-select
    v-model="project_data.country"
    label="text"
    :options="project_data.countries"
    :state="errors.length > 0 ? false : null"
    :reduce="text => text.value" 
/>
```

Now, on my local I can see the option value like this :

[image]

But on the server I can see the ID instead of the option value:

[image]

I do not understand why it's happening :(

Basically I am trying to use the `:reduce` props to get the single value as it's defined in the doc: https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#transforming-selections

Comment: data source is same for local and server ? If yes, it should behave same in both the places

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Yes, all same

Comment: If possible, can you please post the data which `project_data.countries` contains ? and please verify it in both local and server.